# Convert VMDK to ISO

Tags: virtualbox, iso-image, vmware-player, disk-image

I have a disk image that is in VMDK format, and I would like to convert this to an ISO so that I could use this outside of a virtual environment. I know that, at first impression, these formats don't seem compatible, but I am **positive** that this VMDK is simply a disk image, one that would work just dandy in ISO format.

Apparently there are a few tools with Unix command line that allow to [convert a disk image in VMDK format to an ISO](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/convert-vm-iso). However, I was wondering if there are any tools, either within VMWare Player, VirtualBox, etc... or some other third party tool that could easily perform this conversion.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and no. An ISO is a disk image of a CD specifically, and the VMDK is one of a hard drive.

There's ways to mount a VMDK directly - [vmware discmount comes to mind](http://www.vmware.com/download/eula/diskmount_ws_v55.html) as does its [linux counterpart vmware-mount.pl](http://www.novell.com/communities/node/4854/accessing-files-on-a-vmdk-without-booting-the-virtual-machine) , or you can convert it to quite a few formats with [qemu-img programme](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Images#Converting_image_formats).

There're also distro specific remastering software like [remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/) you can run from your disk image to convert it into an installer or livecd image as per your needs.

I can't tell you which is the best solution but that covers nearly every method i can think of.