# Accessing a VMDK / installing a VMware product

Tags: mount, vmdk

I took an old computer that I was getting ready to wipe, and converted it to a VMware virtual machine so I could continue to access both files and programs/settings from the computer.  I stored this virtual machine on an external USB hard drive.  When I got a new PC with ample hard drive space, I transferred the virtual machine to that hard drive.

I cannot access this VMDK.  The vmware-mount tool fails to mount the disk, and neither VMware Workstation nor VMware Player will install on this computer due to one of the MSI packages failing.

Is there another method for accessing the contents of a VMDK, or a way to fix one of the established methods that isn't working for me?

EDIT: I believe the MSI file which is failing to execute properly in the install sequence of all VMware products is called "vmwarevmcisockets64.msi" or something very similar. Can I circumvent this problem without reinstalling Windows (as some have had to do)?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this question/answer](https://superuser.com/questions/378945/convert-vmdk-to-iso):

> [...]
>   There's ways to mount a VMDK directly - [vmware discmount comes to
>   mind](http://www.vmware.com/download/eula/diskmount_ws_v55.html) as does its [linux counterpart vmware-mount.pl](http://www.novell.com/communities/node/4854/accessing-files-on-a-vmdk-without-booting-the-virtual-machine) , or you
>   can convert it to quite a few formats with [qemu-img programme](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Images#Converting_image_formats).
>
> There're also distro specific remastering software like
>   [remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/) you can run from your disk image to convert it into
>   an installer or livecd image as per your needs.
>   [...]

VMware Disk Mount is also mentioned in this post although it doesn't work at your computer. You could also try to convert your disk into a QEMU disk image and load it in QEMU but I'd suggest you to fix your installation issues with VMware products. Maybe that solves your problem with Disk Mount, too.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.  I have updated my original question in an effort to get assistance with the installation problem.  Obviously, while using Disk Mount is the most preferable option, installing VMware would at least allow me to access my files again, albeit through a slightly less direct means.

Comment: Don't you have some error messages? How exactly does the installation routine fail?

Comment: The installers fail with the message "The MSI 'C:\Users\USERNA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\vmware_1344873042\vmwarevmcisockets64.msi' failed."  I can click OK, but no further information is given, the installer has already shut down in the background.